Netsuite Rest Api: Item Fulfillment
I'm currently trying to fulfill an item from a Transfer Order via the Netsuite Rest Api, without any luck.
My intention is fulfill a quantity of 1 for a specific line/item id. This will need to update the status of the Transfer Order to partially fulfilled. Once I've fulfilled all items on the transfer order, I intend to create an item receipt for each item and update the status of the Transfer Order to "Received". I cannot get to these steps unless I can create the item fulfillment first.
They provide the following sample payload in their docs but it is incorrect:
{ "item":{ "items":[ { "orderLine":1, "location":6, "itemreceive": true } { "orderLine": 3 "location": 6, "itemreceive": false } ] }
}

using the following url:
POST https://<accountID>/services/rest/record/v1/salesorder/{{SALES_ORDER_ID}}/!transform/itemFulfillment

I understand that the above sample payload is intended for use with a Sales Order, but from my understanding it should work in a similar fashion for a Transfer Order
I've tried multiple payloads, including the following:
{
    "item": {
        "items": [
            {
                "itemreceive": true,
                "orderLine": 1,
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "shipstatus": "C"
}

and using the following url:
POST https://<accountID>/services/rest/record/v1/transferorder/{{TRANSFER_ORDER_ID}}/!transform/itemFulfillment

On all attempts thus far, I receive the following error:
{
    "type": "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Error while accessing a resource. You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.",
            "o:errorPath": "item",
            "o:errorCode": "USER_ERROR"
        }
    ]
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Try this URL:
/transferOrder/<tfoID>/!transform/itemFulfillment
and this body:
{
  "item": {
    "items": [
      {
        "orderLine": 2,
        "quantity": 7
      }
    ]
  }
}

You seem to have already done what I have posted above.
Finally, set 'Default Items to Zero Received/Fulfilled' to true under Setup > Accounting > Accounting Preferences > Order Management.  This last part is the kicker.

that worked perfectly for the transfer order, but I'm getting 400 when trying to create an item fulfillment for a sales order. I have advanced shipping enabled in settings and tried a similar payload with no success. Is there something different I need to do when fulfilling a sales order?

Not that I am aware of.  I already adapted my answer because all I have done via REST request was transforming a PO to a receipt.  By the way, getting that working was a huge guessing game.  Having said that, you would expect making receipts/fulfillments from other records to be about the same...  The documentation as well as the error messages are terrible.  Perhaps try reaching out to NetSuite.  It would be greatly appreciated if you wrote anything you find back here

I've since made a discovery.  That setting I told you to turn on seems to be unnecessary.  You can specify "itemReceive": true/false (note the capital letter on Receive).  If you put itemReceive: false, you need to not include a quantity though.  I have been able to partially and/or fully receive purchase orders regardless of the mentioned setting being on or off.
